# ¿Como mostrar listado de registros con campos incompletos (null)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hola tengo la siguente situacion: 2 tablas relacionadas usuarios y DatosMultiples esta ultima con 54 campos que pueden ser nulos y uno obligatorio para hacer el registro,
y ya que son tantos campos los usuarios han solicitado que no sean obligatorios y poder llenarlos de apoco por lo que se generan muchos valores nulos, el punto es que necesito listar los registros incompletos y no lo he logrado aún, ¿Saben ustedes alguna forma más eficiente que no tenga que hacer una consulta con los 53 IS NULL?

```
SELECT * FROM paciente JOIN multiplesDatos WHWERE md_1 IS NULL AND md_2 IS NULL AND .... md_n IS NULL;
```

En laravel(8) esto funciona pero debe existir otra manera...

```
$reg_null = multiplesDatos::join('usuarios', 'usr_id', '=', 'md_usr_id')
->where('md_1 ', 'IS NULL')
->where('md_2 ', 'IS NULL')
...
->where('md_n ', 'IS NULL')->paginate(5);
```

Ayuda porfavor

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la siguiente consulta:

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE coalesce(column1, column2, column3) IS NULL;

Está sacado de la siguiente consulta y como dice el compañero no debe utilizarse en producción, sólo si quieres comprobar que valores están a null para depurar:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644756/test-for-nulls-in-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Como consulta en producción, sólo conozco la forma de poner todos los filtros.

Un saludo!

Comment: gracias por la referencia... ¡Haaa 53 filtros!, pensé en obtener todos los registros, iterarlos una primera vez para obtener la lista completa y luego una segunda vez verificar si existen valores nulos, si existen guardarlos en un array que y enviarlo a la vista. quizás son muchas vueltas. bueno de todas formas seguiré intentando y buscando gracias

Answer (score 0):

Asi deberia ser, con un ejemplo te muestro:

```
DB::table('users')

    ->whereNull('name')

    ->get();

DB::table('users')

    ->whereNotNull('name')

    ->get();
```